# Need to open a windows form (like a screen saver) after a X time of the system inactivity

Tags: c#, embedded, compact-framework

As mentioned in the question i need to create a screen saver in my application

But i´m struggling to find a method that i can apply in my software

The problem is that i need to detect any kind of activity in the program, and if the time of inactivity if over a certain value, this form shows. And when this form shows after any activity it must hide and the timer must restart

I´m using Visual studio 2015, with the 3.9 compact .NET framework, and i´m developing the application to a windows embedded 2013

Thank you all for the attention

Have a nice day

Comment: The question is too broad. Try to split up your requirements to sub-tasks and search for solutions for each task independently.

Comment: And, most importantly, show what you've tried on your own so far.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerManager subsytem can give this information to you in Windows CE and Windows Mobile.

MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923909.aspx

Blog post example:

https://www.dzhang.com/blog/2010/01/09/detecting-user-activity-or-inactivity-in-windows-mobile

See if these are available in the newer version (Windows Embedded 2013)